# Geometric Proof of the Formula for Simplex Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I was quite impressed by a [beautiful proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8847#8847)<sup>1</sup>  of the formula for n'th triangular number — it's kind of a bijective proof built on the top of geometric summation idea.

**Question**: does this argument generalize to higher dimensions? i.e. can someone prove the formula for n-th «k-dimensional simplex number» this way?

[image: the proof]

For example, the statement for k=3 is that n-th [pyramidal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) is $\binom{n+2}{3}$.

(One obvious fallback would be observing that any ball in the pyramid is characterized by its coordinates<sup>2</sup>, i.e. balls are counted by a [negative binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Multiset_coefficients) — which is exactly the desired result. That's a good proof, but needless to say, that's not the proof I'm looking for.)

<sup>1</sup> original post by [Mariano Suárez-Alvarez](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274/mariano-suarez-alvarez), [cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-n/2288#2288) by [Vaughn Climenhaga](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/876/vaughn-climenhaga)

<sup>2</sup> k-simplex is the subset $x_0+\dots+x_k=1$, $x_i\ge0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, and n-th k-simplex number is the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_0+\dots+x_k=n$

Comment: What is wrong with that proof?

Comment: @Casebash it doesn't generalize the proof I want to generalize (i.e. for k=2 it gives different proof for the formula for n-th triangular number) — so it doesn't answer the question

Comment: BTW, how do you define coordinates on the pyramid? I know how it works for a triangle

Comment: It is fine now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the balls so that the corners of the pyramid have coordinates (1,1,1), (n,1,1), (1,n,1), (1,1,n). Then for the ball at (x,y,z) we see that (x,x+y,x+y+z) is an ordered triple of distinct numbers between 1 and n+2 inclusive. There are $\binom{n+2}{3}$ such triples, and they are clearly in one-to-one correspondence with the balls. Geometrically, this corresponds to drawing planes x=constant, x+y=constant, and x+y+z=constant through a given ball, and seeing where these planes intersect the x axis.

(To compare with the case $k=2$, "straighten" the picture above into a right triangle. Then the diagonal lines become lines x=constant and x+y=constant, and the bottom row of balls (the blue ones) can be identified with the points where these lines intersect the x axis.)

This also works in higher dimensions, giving $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Whether this proof really is any different from the one you suggested in the question can of course be debated...