# Shortcut method to sum n consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

Is there a *shortcut* method to working out the sum of *n* consecutive positive integers?

Firstly, starting at $1 ... 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15.$

Secondly, starting at any other positive integer ...($10$ e.g.): $10 + 11 + 12 + 13 = 46$.

Comment: The solution to the second problem follows from a solution of the first since $(m+1)+\cdots+n=S(n)-S(m)$ where $S(k)=1+\cdots+k$. About the first... the legend says that Gauss as a schoolboy realized quickly that if you sum as $(1+n)+(2+(n-1))+\ldots$ all the summands are the same, thus......

Comment: Alternately, if there are $n$ successive integers, starting with $m+1$, the answer is $mn + (1 + 2 + \ldots + n)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. :)

Comment: BTW: MarkUp is not allowed in subject title of posts. I've removed the asterisks.

Comment: So I thought this was certainly a duplicate. But then I attempted to find such a duplicate, but to no avail. I'm at a loss as to how to effectively search for such a duplicate now.

Comment: @mixedmath, searching this website is more of an art than a science. Typing "consecutive" into the search box brought up question 15225, which covers some of the same territory but isn't exactly a duplicate.

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate of the question its marked as a dupe of. This is asking for a simple formula, the other a detailed proof. Very different things. StackExchange has an epidemic of busy bodies marking things as duplicates unnecessarily and destructively.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Take the average of the first number and the last number, and multiply by the number of numbers.

Comment: ... and this works for any arithmetic progression

Comment: computation Sum = total_numbers * ( first / 2 + last / 2 )

Comment: @Miguel I believe your order of operations is wrong. It should be:
Sum = total_numbers * (first + last) / 2

Comment: @PaulHazen well depends on who is the user, computers do the first/2 and add last/2 in this order, calculators might use the "human" order, which would end up in a total different result. Either way, yes a/2  + b/2 is (a+b)/2 so your solution is more clear and its shorter and removed doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

The rule, as given by Gerry's answer (and the generalization as per Henry's comment) can be easily visualized, in a similar way as we deduce the area of a rectangular trapezium:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leon. Great illustration of the math.