# Doubt about series - which series is this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of  n consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers)

I really can't remember (if I have ever known this): which series is this and how to demonstrate its solution?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: This is not a series, since there is no infinite sum :-) It is a summation identity, rather standard, and can be easily proved by mathematical induction on $n$. This is indeed one of the most popular exercises on mathematical induction.

Comment: @Siminore: The term "series" is commonly used for both finite and infinite summations.

Comment: By the way, there is a beautiful visual proof of this fact appearing as the top answer to this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words

Comment: @Brad You are right, the very definition of series is a bit ambiguous. I was just joking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Arithmetic Series starting from $1$ with difference $1$.
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... +n = {n (n+1) \over 2}$$
1#[Check this out](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/pww.shtml).
2#[There's one another](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProofWithoutWords12N1NChoose2/) related one.

Answer (score 3):

Write out this sum twice, once is direct order, and once in reverse:
$$
   \begin{align}
       &1 + &2 + &\ldots+ &(n-1)+ &n &=s \\
       &n + &(n-1)+ & \ldots+ &2+ &1 &=s 
   \end{align}
$$
Now add up column-wise:
$$
    (n+1) + (n+1) + \ldots + (n+1) + (n+1) = 2s
$$
There are exactly $n$ terms here (as many as the number of terms in the sum). Hence:
$$
    n(n+1) = 2s
$$
Now solve for $s$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a series. This sum is named Gauss sum and that formula $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ you can prove it using induction.

The exercise starts from the following sum: $1+2+ \ldots +100$ and the way you can classify the terms of this sum.

$1+2+ \ldots + 100 = (1+100)+ (2+99)+ \ldots (50+51$).

for more information I think the following link : http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/math99/math99155.htm it is a good one.

Comment: As @Brad pointed out, the term "series" is not completely wrong. A series is the sequence obtained by summing the terms of a given sequence. In this case, the given sequence is $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,n,0,0,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$S = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \ldots + 1$.  So $2S = (n+1) + \ldots + (n+1)$.  Since the $(n+1)$ appears $n$ times, $$S = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$