# Computing value of the series $S_N = \sum_{k=1}^{k=N} a_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of  n consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers)

I am working on engineering problem where I have a series of the form:

$S_N = \sum_{k=1}^{k=N} a_k$

were $a_k = k$. I'm  wondering, how do I compute the value of $S_N$ for $N=365$ and what type of series is this?

Comment: arithmetic series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_N=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_N$ where $a_k=k$

$\implies s_N=1+2+3+\cdots+N$ which is an arithmetic progression with $a=1$ and common difference $d=1$

$\implies s_N=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum