# Why does $\binom{n}{2} =[ (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3)+\cdots +1]$?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I was recently doing a homework problem that involved finding the number of lines used to connect a given number of points on a circle. Looking at it logically, I saw that that for the first point, there would be $n-1$ lines you could draw (where $n$ is the number of points on the circle) and the next point would have $n-2$ lines because you're not repeating the line between point $1$ and point $2$. It made sense that this would continue until point $n$, at which point there would be zero lines you can draw.

This meant that if you just add up all of those, you'd get the number.

For example, in the picture below there are $12$ points, so

$11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 66$ lines.

[image: Image of how the lines are connected]

That's all fine, but the weird thing was, when I looked in the back of the book, the answer was given as $\binom{n}{2}$, which also equals $66$. What's the relationship? Why are the two equal?

Comment: From one point of view, your first paragraph could be regarded as answering your question. (But there's more to know about it than that.) $\qquad$

Comment: What software did you use to draw the illustrations? $\qquad$

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers.

Comment: Every line connects exactly two points. Therefore, the number of distinct lines is exactly the number of ways of choosing $2$ points - i.e. $n \choose 2$.

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8847#8847).

Comment: Shouldn't it be obvious that $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of lines to connect $n$ points? Each line corresponds to a choice of two of the points. From that perspective it would seem to me that the first paragraph is simply a proof of the fact that $\binom{n}{2} = (n-1)+\cdots+1$... Also read Sudhadeep's link; it's my favorite proof by picture.

Comment: Ya, I've been thinking about it and it is sort of obvious

Comment: As @MichaelHardy asked earier, which software did you use for drawing this diagram?

Comment: I just got it from [this](http://www.mathrecreation.com/2013_04_01_archive.html) article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$$

And

$$\binom nk = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

In particular

$$\binom n2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k$$

Another way to see it is by induction. In particular $\binom 1 2 = 0$, and $\binom {n+1}{2} = \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2}$, which probably makes the identity seem a bit less "random".

Comment: Downvoting because the OP is aware of the truth of the relationship but is looking for a combinatorial connection.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Is he really? As I read the question (the last paragraph in particular), it is about the identity; not the combinatorics.

Comment: See comment on the other similar answer

Comment: Wait, how do you know that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = n(n-1)/2$$? Is that a well known equation?

Comment: @samarbarrett Yes it is a well know equation: http://bit.ly/1Cv5olc    The sum of the first $n$ numbers is: $\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. So, the sum of the first $n-1$ numbers is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k = \frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

You have $\binom n 2 = \frac{n(n-1)}2$. Now, a famous formula says that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k = \frac{n(n-1)}2.
$$
This can be proved by induction. To understand it - at least when $n$ is odd - write
$$
1 + \ldots + (n-1) = (1 + (n-1)) + (2 + (n-2)) + \ldots,
$$
which is $(n-1)/2$ times $n$.

Comment: Downvoting because the OP is aware of the truth of the relationship but is looking for a combinatorial connection.

Comment: Do you really think so? He/she writes "That's all fine, but the weird thing was, when I looked in the back of the book, the answer was given as $\binom n 2$, which also equals 66. What's the relationship? Why are the two equal?" I think it's ridiculous to downvote for such a reason.

Comment: @StellaBiderman what part of the body of the question indicates the OP is aware of the relationship? And according to the title of the question, it is exactly about the relationship. Maybe you're right and maybe not, but a downvote here isn't fair

Comment: Upon rereading the OP I agree with you guys about it being the wrong action to take.

Answer (score 1):

SBareS has provided you with a good answer.  Here is a combinatorial proof.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ with two elements. Of these subsets, there are $k - 1$ subsets with largest element $k$, with $1 \leq k \leq n$.  Hence,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (k - 1) = \binom{n}{2}$$

In the problem you did, think of the vertices as numbered.  You counted the diagonals in which the vertex with the smaller number was $k$, with $1 \leq k \leq 12$.  That yields the sum 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{12} (12 - k) = 11 + 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 66$$
Notice that 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (n - k) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (k - 1) = \binom{n}{2}$$
since the summands are the same, just written in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get the result stated directly is to note that if you have $n$ vertices, to pick a diagonal is to select a pair of vertices, which means in all there are $\binom{n}{2}$ diagonals.

Another way is to pick each of the $n$ vertices, it participates in $n - 1$ diagonals connecting it to the other vertices, thus $n (n - 1)$ in all. But this counts each diagonal twice, once for each of its ends. Thus $n (n - 1) / 2 = \binom{n}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You just explained it.

Say you have a mixture of blue and white balls.  You draw 11 and two of them are blue.  How many ways might the two blue balls be arranged?

If the first ball is in position 1, the other ball might be in any of the other 10 positions.  If the first ball is in position 2, the second ball may be in any of 9 positions because you don't double count the {1,2} combination which had the first ball in position 1.  And so on.  It may be easier to ser that the triangular sum equals the conbination function when you use balls.  But tge lines are being counted the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Order the elements of $N={1,...,n}$. There are obviously n-1 two element subsets containing 1. We have counted all the subsets containing 1, so remove 1 from $N$. Now there are obviously n-2 two element subsets contining 2 in $N/{1}$. Rinse and repeat until you have exhausted the set.