# Find closed form for $a_{1}=2, a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n+6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have determined that $a_{2} = 10, a_{3} = 19, a_{4} = 29, a_{5} = 40, a_{6} = 52,$ and $a_{7} = 65$. I can see that there is a pattern in that each value increases by 8, then 9, then 10, then 11, then 12, etc. but I am having difficulty making an equation for it.

I thought I had it when I realized that $a_{2} = 9+1, a_{3} = 16 + 4, a_{4} = 25 + 4, a_{5} = 36 + 4,$ and so on, but then I realized it was not very consistent. Also, the difference between $a_{n} - (n-1)^2$ starts to get smaller as the value of n increases, and then begins to increase again later.

Am I going about this completely wrong? Is there a way to find a closed form for $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n+6$ when $a_{1}=2$?

Comment: Since the second difference is constant, there will be a quadratic solution.  In fact $a_3=16+3$ and $a_6=49+3$ and $a_7= 65+1$ so the pattern you almost spotted is incorrect.

Comment: 2    10    19    29    40    52    65    79    94   110   127   145   164   184   205   227   250   274    299   325 $$a_1,a_2,,,,a_{20}$$

Comment: sequence of $a_n-a_{n-1}$ is (20 terms) $$\\$$ 8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24     25    26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

reorder the terms:

$$
a_1=2
$$
$$
a_2=a_1+2+6=2+2+6
$$
$$
a_3=a_2+3+6=2+2+6+3+6=2+(2+3)+2\cdot 6
$$
$$
a_4=a_3+4+6=2+(2+3)+2\cdot 6+4+6=2+(2+3+4)+3\cdot 6
$$

this suggests:

$$
a_n=2+\frac{(n-1)(2+n)}{2}+6(n-1)
$$

Now prove that it works giving $a_n=a_{n-1}+n+6$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_m=b_m+Am^2+Bm+C$

$2=a_1=b_1+A+B+C\iff b_1=?$

$$n+6=a_n-a_{n-1}=b_n-b_{n-1}+2An+B-A$$

Set $B-A=6,2A=1$ so that $b_n=b_{n-1}=\cdots=b_1=?$

Answer (score 1):

For $n \geq 2$ we have:

$$a_n =a_1 + \sum\limits_2^n (n+6) = a_1 + \sum\limits_2^n n + \sum\limits_2^n 6 $$

Can you take it from here?

EDIT:
[This result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers) can help you with the first sum.