# Sum of (sum of Nx consecutive) N consecutive numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

## Research

I know that I can use Gauss' Trick for finding the sum of consecutive numbers. `n/2 * (start + end)`

This is illustrated here: [Sum of  n consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers)

## Question

I am trying to find a shorter solution, (one without loops) to the algorithm below: (sorry for lack of LaTeX knowledge)

For each number from 1 to N, find the sum of (the sum the numbers from 1 to Nx)

### Expanded Version:

Given N = 4

```
N1: [(1)] + 
N2: [(1 + 2) + (1)] + 
N3: [(1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2) + (1)] +
N4: [(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2) + (1)]
```

### Using Gauss' Trick

Given N = 4

```
N1: [1/2 * (1 + 1)] +
N2: [2/2 * (1 + 2)] +
N3: [3/2 * (1 + 3)] +
N4: [4/2 * (1 + 4)]
```

### Looking for a "Double Guass' Trick"

**So, is there a mathematical way to calculate this "second level" approximation without needing to loop through 1-N?**

Comment: What's $x$?  Do you just mean $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac {i(i+1)}2$?  But that is just $\frac 12\times \sum_{i=1}^N  i^2  +\frac 12\times \sum_{i=1}^N i$.  And both of those sums are well known polynomials in $N$.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for a general discussion of sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N i^k$  though here you only need the cases $k=1,2$.

Comment: I will modify the title of the question. X should be N.

Comment: But it's not just the title, your phrase "find the sum of (the sum the numbers from 1 to Nx)" doesn't really make sense.  Again, what is $x$?  In my first comment I made a guess as to what you meant to ask, but I do not know if I guessed correctly.

Comment: @lulu In `Nx`, `x` is the iteration number of `N`. I am trying to find a summation inside of a summation. I am not sure how to word or write the formula for this, but I feel like the `Expanded Version` of my question illustrates the steps which should help you extract the meaning.

Comment: Well, do you think that the formula in my first comment matches your intent?  If so, then I think the issue is resolved.  If not, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @lulu I just took a closer look at your comment and it 100% represents what I am trying to do. I am taking a look at the "but that is just... " part now. Is there an algebraic representation to that? My math skills are somewhat lacking.

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for the kind of simplification Gauss made instead of having to calculate out `sum(i=1, N) i`

Comment: So that would be $\Psi(N)=\frac {N(N+1)(2N+1)}{12}+\frac {N(N+1)}4$.  The sequence of values is $\{1,4,10,20,35,\cdots\}$   These are the so called [tetrahedral numbers](https://oeis.org/A000292).  Note:  I believe the polynomial I wrote out can be simplified somewhat, I did not try.

Comment: Checking this out now. If you want to put it in an answer, I will accept and up vote. What do you mean by "both of those sums are well known polynomials in N?"

Comment: Look up the article I linked to on Faulhaber,   $\sum_{i=1}^Ni^2=\frac {N(N+1)(2N+1)}6$ is well known and you certainly know $\sum_{i=1}^N i=\frac {N(N+1)}2$

Comment: Note my polynomial simplifies to $\Psi(N)=\frac {N(N+1)(N+2)}6$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! This just cut so many iterations off of my algorithm!!! I appreciate the time and references!