# What is the formula of the summation of integers from i=0 to i=N?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for formula for sum of sequence 1+2+3+…+n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-n)

I have this sigma:$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}(i-1)$$

is it $$\frac{n^2-n}{2}\quad?$$

Comment: sorry, I've wrote sigma then inter in the tag and I didn't know it was measure theory :S , yes I know this formula and wt I did is subtract N from it then I got what I wrote in the question,is it right?

Comment: @Sosy: Yes, that is a correct argument. I've closed this question as a duplicate, because this question has come up before here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elementary proof that $\sum_{i = 1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which legend has is due to Gauss. For a proof, see my blog post at [Math ∩ Programming](http://jeremykun.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/sums-of-the-first-n-numbers-squares/).

What you have is the same as $\sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} i$, since adding zero is trivial. So your thing is correct, and substituting $n$ for $N-1$ we get $N(N-1)/2$, which is what you have.

Comment: In fact, the legend does *not* say Gauss invented the formula (he didn't), but just that Gauss re-discovered it as a schoolboy.

Comment: Right. I meant the particular proof is due to Gauss (which might also be untrue).