# How does this image prove the identity $1+2+3+4\cdots + (n-1) = \binom{n}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, intuition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for formula for sum of sequence 1+2+3+…+n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-n)

**Proof without words:**

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ [image]

> How does this image prove the identity $1+2+3+4\cdots + (n-1) = \binom{n}{2}$?

I found this [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words); could anybody explain this in a lucid manner?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-n/2288#2288

Comment: Is it ironic that the post is titled "Proof without words"? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows that every yellow circle uniquely determines a pair of blue circles and vice versa. The number of yellow ones is the LHS, the number of pairs of blue ones is the RHS. Cute!

Comment: I don't think I can see the proof yet :/

Comment: There are 3 steps (ok maybe 4). 1)every yellow circle uniquely determines a pair of blue circles and vice versa 2)The number of yellow ones is the LHS 3)the number of pairs of blue ones is the RHS. 4)All of this implies the equality we want.  Which of these are confusing?

Comment: 1) was confusing,but I guess I got it,is it like going in same the direction as shown in the example for every other yellow discs?

Comment: and number 4 too.

Comment: Exactly. And conversely, from any pair of blue discs you can go up in these directions and the lines will intersect at a yellow disc.

Comment: You should be able to figure out 4 (as in: 1)y=pb 2)y=lhs 3)pb=rhs imply 4)rhs=lhs).