# Proving that the given function $F:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is bijective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the function $F:\mathbb N\times\mathbb  N\to \mathbb N$ defined by 
$$F(a,b)=\frac{(a+b-2)(a+b-1)}{2} +a$$ How can I prove that it is a bijective function? I proved it using Partial derivatives by assuming the function to be continuous and defined on $\mathbb{R}$. But how can I prove it using definition of one-one and onto functions?

Comment: The function is defined on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. In order to prove that it is bijective, you have to prove that it is *one-to-one* and *onto*. No partial derivatives here !

Comment: If $0\in\mathbb N$, then $F$ is not injective, e.g. $F(1,0)=F(0,3)$.

Comment: This is almost the same question as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective), the only difference is that there integers start with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here assuming $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$.

Notice that $G=2F(a,b)$ always falls between $(a+b-2)^2$ and $(a+b)^2$. In fact $G$ is always greater than the number halfway between $(a+b-2)^2$ and $(a+b-1)^2$ and less than the number halfway between $(a+b-1)^2$ and $(a+b)^2$. This determines $(a+b-1)^2$, hence $a+b$. Furthermore, $G$ is greater than $(a+b-1)^2$ if and only if $a>b$. The exact value of $G$ then determines $a$ and $b$ specifically. This shows it's injective.

To prove it's onto just notice that there are exactly $a+b-1$ many even numbers between those halfway points, i.e. the number of possibilities for $(a,b)$ for $a+b$ fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument for injectivity.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 2}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ defined by $f(u) = (u-2)(u-1)/2$. Note that
$$\begin{align}
2(f(u+1) - f(u)) &= (u-1)u - (u-2)(u-1) \\
&= u^2 - u - u^2 + 3u - 2 \\
&= 2u - 2
\end{align}$$
so $f(u+1) - f(u) = u-1$. Therefore $f$ is an increasing function, and in general, if $v > u$ we have
$$f(v) - f(u) \geq u-1$$

Now suppose that $F(a,b) = F(c,d)$. Consider two cases.

**Case 1** $a+b = c+d$

Then $0 = F(a,b) - F(c,d) = a-c$, so $a = c$, and therefore $b = d$.

**Case 2** without loss of generality, assume $a+b > c+d$

Then
$$\begin{align}
0 &= F(a,b) - F(c,d) \\
&= f(a+b) + a - f(c+d) - c \\
&\geq (c+d-1) + a-c \\
&= a+d - 1
\end{align}$$
so $a + d \leq 1$. But this is impossible since both $a$ and $d$ are $\geq 1$.