# Is there any mathematical operation that can be reversed to two unique numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science, integer-partitions

Is there any mathematical operation “op”, such that when applied to two integers a, b: a op b = n. We can use that n and reverse the operation, to get n = a op b?

For example, the sum is not reversible to two integers, since 5 + 7 = 12, but we don’t know if 12 = 2 + 10 or 3 + 9 etc.

Comment: $2^a 3^b$, or $p^a q^b$ for any distinct prime numbers $p, q$.

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1350868/42969

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723327/42969 and the linked posts.

Comment: $a + b^{-1}$ would return $a$ as the integer portion, and then investing the decimal portion gets $b$ as $\frac{1}{b} < 1$. But this would only work if you knew beforehand that they were both integers

Comment: An idea (Cantor) is to take $n$ as the integer whose even digits are the digits of $a$ and the odd digits the digits of $b$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple bijection $\mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478277/simple-bijection-mathbb-n-0-times-mathbb-n-0-to-mathbb-n-0)

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ doesn’t have to be an integer, I can define an operator.

For all integers $a$ and $b$, “$\bullet$” defines as follows:

$$a \bullet b = a+b+ai,$$

where $i$ is the square root of $-1$.

Here using $i$, we aim to save one of the elements to turn back. If we define reverse operator as below,

$$\circ(z) = (\operatorname{Im}(z), \operatorname{Re}(z) - \operatorname{Im}(z)),$$

we obtain $(a,b)$ again.

If $n$ has to be an integer, maybe we can define an operator based on “fundamental theorem of arithmetic”.

According to this theorem, all positive integers can be represented as a product of prime powers in a unique way. One can define an operator using this uniqueness.

Comment: Why $a+b+ai$ and not simply $a+bi$? :-)

Comment: :))) Yes, I wrote the first thing that came to my mind, but this is a better method. Actually, I wanted the operator to perform at least one action. The operation there could have been a very complicated function rather than a+b.

Answer (score 0):

What about prime number factorisation?

$$f(a,b) = 2^a \cdot 3^b = n$$

Obviously, $n$ can only be a number, which is only divisible by prime factors $2$ and $3$ (like $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $9$, $12$, $16$, $18$, $24$, ...), but for each of those number, you can easily find $a$ and $b$ back.

Comment: I like that approach. Is there anyway we could also make a map with negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

For an $m \times n$ matrix, you can always map the pair of indexes $(i,j) \in \{(1,1), \ldots, (1,n), \ldots, (m,1), \ldots, (m,n)\}$ to a single value in $\{1, \ldots, mn\}$:  $$(i,j) \to n(i-1)+j.$$  It is a bijection, hence it is reversible:  $$r(i,j) = n(i-1)+j \leftrightarrows \begin{cases} i=\lceil r/n\rceil, \\ j=(r-1)\bmod n+1; \end{cases}$$  provided that you know both $m$ and $n$ at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take any bijection *f* from ℤ × ℤ into ℤ (there is at least one as the domain and co-domain have the same cardinality; one could also choose *f* to be surjective). Then, its inverse function "takes you back."