# Formula for the sum of the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

How was this derived as the sum of the following sequence...

$$S_n = (n–1)+(n–2)+(n–3)+\dotsb+1=\frac{n\cdot(n–1)}{2}$$

Please could you guide me in the right direction...

$$\begin{aligned}
S_n &= 1+\dotsb+ (n-3)+(n-2)+ (n-1) \\
S_n &= (n–1)+(n–2)+(n–3)+\dotsb+1 \\
2S_n &= (n-1+1)+(n-2+n-3)+(n-3+n-2)+(n-1+1) \\
S_n &= \dotsc
\end{aligned}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here...

Edit solved: forgot to times n by last term.

Comment: Read here, [link](http://www.jimloy.com/algebra/gauss.htm),- nice story about young **Gauss**.

Comment: Proof by induction is also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $S_n$ in two ways, add them up...
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
S_n &=& 1 &+& 2 &+& \ldots &+& (n-2) &+& (n-1) \\
S_n &=& (n-1) &+& (n-2) &+& \ldots &+& 2 &+& 1 \\ \hline
2S_n &=& 1 + (n - 1) &+& 2 + (n - 2) &+& \ldots &+& (n - 2) + 2 &+& (n - 1) + 1 \\
     &=& n &+& n &+& \ldots &+& n &+& n \\
     &=& n (n - 1) & & & & & & & &
\end{array}$$
...and divide both sides by $2$ to get $S_n = n(n-1)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, but you have things lined up wrong.

$S_n=1+2+3+...+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)$

$S_n=(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+3+2+1$

$2S_n=(n-1+1)+(n-2+2)+...$

Maybe someone else can line that up better, but you should see where this is going.

Comment: @Hmm Where's that extra 1 coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  Specifically, consider the difference $S_{n+1} - S_n$.