# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n}{2}(n+1)$ without words?

Tags: alternative-proof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

Is there a picture proof for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n}{2}(n+1)$?

Comment: http://www.wolaver.org/teaching/clip_image002.gif

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn/2288#2288

Comment: Even though the questions are different, I have voted to close a dupe. Any proof without words can be added to that question.

Comment: Draw an $n$ by $n+1$ rectangular array of lattice points, and split it into two equal halves along an almost diagonal. Taking $n=4$ is probably good enough. Or else equivalently take an $n+1$ times $n+1$ array, erase the main NW to SE diagonal, and slide the lower remaining half up by $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw an $n$ by $n+1$ rectangular array of lattice points, and split it into two equal halves along an almost diagonal. Taking $n=4$ or $n=5$ is probably good enough.

Or else, equivalently, take an $n+1$ by  $n+1$ square array of dots, and erase  the main Northwest to Southeast diagonal. Then slide the points of the lower remaining half up by $1$.

**Remark:** Logically speaking, this cannot be an acceptable answer!  A request for a proof without words has been answered by using $\dots$ *words*.

Comment: I'm sorry I formulated the title badly. I really meant "a proof using a picture."

Comment: @user26345: Your question was very well formulated. I was just making a joke about my answer.