# Sum of n different positive integers is less than 100. What is the greatest possible value for n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

I am stumped on the following question:

> > The sum of n different positive integers is less than 100. What is the greatest possible value for n?
> >
> > a) 10, b) 11, c) 12, d) 13, e) 14

The answer is d).

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: Relevant: [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sum of different numbers is least when it's consecutive numbers from beginning from $1$. The sum would be 
$$ {n(n+1) \over 2} \leq 100 $$
This inequality gives $  n \leq 13 $.

Comment: is something wrong??

Comment: I am just curious how you got n<=13. I am trying to solve from $n^2+n-200$.

Comment: The quadratic gives $13.650...$ and $-14.6...$. So should I just consider 13 ? and why ?

Comment: @Rejeshwar $n=14$ yields $105$ thus $n\leq 13$ (strict monotonicity).

Comment: @Rajeshwar $13.650$ gives $100$ ... less than it gives less than 100. greatest possible natural number less than 13.650 is 13

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out

Answer (score 2):

I would try to make the summands as small as possible. I.e. $1+2+3+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2<100.$ Thus, compare $(13)( 14)/2$ with $(14)(15)/2.$

Answer (score 1):

As 
\begin{equation}
1+2+\cdots +n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
and $\dfrac{13\cdot 14}{2}=91$. We have $n=13.$ In fact, $\dfrac{14\cdot 15}{2}=105$.

Comment: $ \dfrac{14\cdot 15}{2}=\color{red}{105}$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, to fit the most numbers in to the sum, you will need to do $1+2+3+\cdots$.

You could manually work out how many numbers you can fit in, before you get to 100, or you could use the fact that:

$ 1+2+3+\cdots+n = \frac{n}{2}(n+1) $

So you want:

$\frac{n}{2}(n+1) < 100$.

$n(n+1) < 200$

Now, you could solve the quadratic, and find the valid regions, but I'm going to try it another (probably worse) way:

If you had $n(n+1) =200$, you can see that $\sqrt{200}$ is directly between $n$ and $n+1$.

So for $n(n+1) < 200$, the highest value of $n$ will always be either $\rm floor(\sqrt{200})$ or if that is too many, $\rm floor(\sqrt{200}) - 1$.

Comment: The quadratic gives $13.650...$ and $-14.6...$. So should I just consider 13 ? and why ?