# Geometric interpretation for sum of fourth powers

Tags: summation, proof-without-words

Summing the first $n$ first powers of natural numbers:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12n(n+1)$$
and there is a [geometric proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn/34400#34400) involving two copies of a 2D representation of $(1+2+\cdots+n)$ that form a $n\times(n+1)$-rectangle.

---

Similarly,
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$$ 
has a [geometric proof](http://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/the-sum-of-consecutive-squares-formula/) (scroll down just a bit til you see the wooden blocks) involving six copies of a 3D representation of $(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)$ that form a $n\times(n+1)\times(2n+1)$-rectangular solid.

---

And similarly,
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac14n^2(n+1)^2$$
has a proof involving four copies of a 4D representation of $(1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3)$ that form a $n\times n\times(n+1)\times(n+1)$-rectangular hypersolid in four-space. I can't find a resource to demonstrate this last one better, but I've sketched it out for $n=3$, sketching the four dimensions using a $4\times4$ grid for two dimensions, and within each cell a $3\times 3$ grid for the other two. (Try it - it's fun!) Here's a smaller $n=2$ version. Note that $1^3+2^3$ is represented by some 4D blocks $1\times1^3+1\times2^3$ that are configured in a way that makes use of all four dimensions.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet}\\
{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet}\\
{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{blue} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}\\
{\color{blue} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}
\end{array} \\\hline
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{green} \bullet} & {\color{green} \bullet}\\
{\color{green} \bullet} & {\color{green} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}\\
{\color{green} \bullet} & {\color{magenta} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{blue} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}\\
{\color{blue} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}
\end{array} \\\hline
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{green} \bullet} & {\color{green} \bullet}\\
{\color{green} \bullet} & {\color{green} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{magenta} \bullet} & {\color{magenta} \bullet}\\
{\color{magenta} \bullet} & {\color{magenta} \bullet}
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{cc}
{\color{magenta} \bullet} & {\color{magenta} \bullet}\\
{\color{magenta} \bullet} & {\color{magenta} \bullet}
\end{array} \\
\end{array}$$
This is a $2\times2\times3\times3$ rectangular hypersolid made up of four copies of $1\cdot1^3+1\cdot2^3$.

---

So we move on to fourth powers:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\frac1{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$$
This time the polynomial does not completely factor. I would like to know if anyone can find a similar geometric proof. It would involve 30 copies of a 5D representation of $(1^4+2^4+\cdots+n^4)$ forming a 5D hypersolid, one of whose 2-faces somehow works out to have area $3n^2+3n-1$, with the orthogonal edge lengths being $n$, $n+1$, and $2n+1$. I know it seems hopeless...30 copies? $3n^2+3n-1$? But it would make for some nice art.

It would be a nice start if there were some sort of connection between $30$ and a symmetry group of $\mathbb{R}^5$. For instance, if there were a subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}_5$ whose order was some large divisor of $30$, then that might help place the $30$ blocks of volume $1^5$ into their configuration.

Comment: +1. But I want no part in this madness...

Comment: In the same way that there are nice 'visual' proofs of $\sum_kk^3$ that instead go through its representation as $\left(\sum_kk\right)^2$, maybe you can wedge 5 copies of $\sum_kk^4$ together and find $(3n^2+3n-1)$ copies of $\sum_kk^2$ in the result?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Interesting!

Comment: Are you familiar with the book: Charming Proofs: A Journey into Elegant Mathematics (Dolciani Mathematical Expositions)? I believe there are others also for visualizing proofs and they are very interesting indeed.

Comment: @Amzoti I'm not - I'll look for it at our local giant used book store.

Comment: Alex, you can actually peruse pages and see some of the proof strategies using Amazon. Here are some other choices to peruse: 1. Proofs without Words: Exercises in Visual Thinking (Classroom Resource Materials) (v. 1), 2. Proofs Without Words II: More Exercises in Visual Thinking (Classroom Resource Materials) (v. 2). I believe there are others too as I have seen some for topics such as Linear Algebra (IIRC). Enjoy!

Comment: 30 comes from the fact that the Bernoulli number $B_4=-1/30$. See "Faulhaber's formula" in Wikipedia.

Comment: @pharmine, Yes and so does $6$ in the sum of squares formula. But perhaps coincidentally there is a way to configure 6 shapes together as seen in the link. I'm asking if coincidentally this can be done with thirty 5-dimensional shapes. (I doubt that it can, but I'd love to see it if I'm wrong.)

Comment: I'm certainly gonna ask my teacher about this. He thinks he knows everything, and rules out answeres in many good books.

Comment: Here is a cute article on [Faulhaber's triangle](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Torabi-Dashti-CMJ-2011.pdf)

Comment: This [mathologer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw1kRz83Fj0) is not exactly an answer to your question, but goes into the general formula for any power in an accessible, visual way.

Answer (score 25):

On this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Proofs-without-Words-Exercises-Classroom/dp/0883857006](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857006)

Is given the following solution:

[image: Proofs Without Words]

I guess that with a bit of calculation it is possible to get to the formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^4$$

I know that we miss all the stuff about the fifth dimension... but in this way the proof is much easier to visualize...

Comment: +1 This is cool, but I'm holding out for five-dimensional blocks :)

Answer (score 4):

Your construction sounds like that of the **Ehrhart polynomials**. Snooping around Wikipedia a bit gives us confirmation.  From the article [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number):

> In modern mathematics, figurate numbers are formalized by the Ehrhart polynomials.
>
> The Ehrhart polynomial $L(P,t)$ of a polyhedron $P$ is a polynomial that counts the number of integer points in a copy of $P$ that is expanded by multiplying all its coordinates by the number $t$. The Ehrhart polynomial of a pyramid whose base is the unit square $[0,1]^2 \times 0$, and whose apex is an integer point at height one above the base plane $(0,0,1)$ has Ehrhart polynomial $ \frac{1}{6}(t+1)(t+2)(2t+3)$.

In your problem the choice of [convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope) is pretty clear.  It is the convex hull of the [hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) $[0,1]^4 \times 0$ and the point $(0,0,0,0,1)$.

---

Reading the article [Ehrhart Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial) we get some definitions:

> Let $P$ be a polytope with vertices in a lattice $L$ (e.g. $L = \mathbb{Z}^d$ then) $L(P,t) = \# (tP \cap L)$ is a polynomial in $t$, called the Erhart polynomial of degree $d = \dim L$.
>
> The Ehrhart polynomial of the *interior* (those strictly inside $P$) is $L(\text{int}(P), t)= (-1)^d L(P,-t)$.

Comment: But a convex polytope is not an analogy to blocks. With blocks in the smaller dimensional cases, we can see _directly_ the connection to $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$. The polytope answer to this question for summing $1+2+\cdots+n$ would be two triangles glued together instead of the familiar interlocking stairsteps.

Comment: Well, yes, $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ is the value of an Ehrhart polynomial for the 'hybercubic pyramid'. But does this help to compute the sum?

Comment: @alex.jordan Did you notice the sum of squares *divides* sum of 4th powers?
$$ \sum k^2 =\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1) \Bigg| \sum k^4 = \frac{1}{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$$
The [blog](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/the-sum-of-consecutive-squares-formula/) you mentioned has **two** solutions. One uses a triangular lattice. $$ .$$  The [volume of a pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Volume) is $\frac{1}{3}Ah$ where $A$ is the base and $h$ is the height.  By [Cavalieri principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) we don't worry if the Pyramid is slanted or not.

Comment: I think you are confused about what the question asks here. You're providing true statements that are not answering the question. They are tangentially related, but I think you have missed exactly what is being asked for here. How does the polytope that you describe clearly represent $1^4+2^4+\cdots+n^4$? In the same way that the stairstep shape clearly represents $1+2+\cdots+n$?

Comment: And yes, of course $\sum k^2$ divides $\sum k^4$. All $\sum k^i$ are divisible by $n$ and $(n+1)$. And all $\sum k^{2i}$ are additionally divisible by $(2n+1)$. So not only does $\sum k^2$ divide $\sum k^4$, but also $\sum k^6$, $\sum k^8$, etc. I haven't seen a way to use that to help with my geometric question though.

Comment: @alex.jordan This problem is very hard.  I have no idea where these sum-of-powers formulas come from.  While Erhart polynomials generalize figurate numbers of any kind, I am learning they are difficult to compute in general.  They are related to [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) or [Dehn-Somerville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn%E2%80%93Sommerville_equations) relations.

Comment: @alex.jordan Well no; $\sum k^2$ doesn't divide $\sum k^{2a}$ for all $n$, but it does indeed divide $5\sum k^4, 7\sum k^6, 5\sum k^8, 11\sum k^{10}, 455\sum k^{12}, \sum k^{14}, 85\sum k^{16}$.

Comment: @RosieF I was speaking with polynomial divisibility, referring to the polynomial factors $n$, $(n+1)$, and $(2n+1)\sim(n+1/2)$. So divisibility in $\mathbb{Q}[n]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[n]$. But your point is well taken.