# Sum of fourth powers in terms of sum of squares

Tags: summation

The sum of the fourth powers of the first $n$ integers can be expressed as a multiple of the sum of squares of the first $n$ integers, i.e.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n r^4&=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^3+3n-1)}{30}\\
&=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\cdot \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 \\
&=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\sum_{r=1}^nr^2 \end{align}$$

> **Question**: Is it possible to show this, purely by manipulating the summand, and without first expressing the summation in closed form and then factoring the sum of squares?

From the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241760/geometric-interpretation-for-sum-of-fourth-powers), we see that

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^4=\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r^2\right)^2-2\sum_{r=1}^n r^2\sum_{j=1}^{r-1}j^2\\
=\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-2\sum_{j=1}^{r-1}j^2\right)$$
but this does not appear to lead anywhere closer to answering the question.

Another approach might be to use Abel's summation formula
$$\sum_{r=1}^n f_r (g_{r+1}-g_r)=\left[f_{n+1}g_{n+1}-f_1g_1\right]-\sum_{r=1}^n g_{r+1}(f_{r+1}-f_r)$$
Putting $f_r=r^2$ and $g_r=\frac {r(r-1)(2r-1)}6$ gives
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^4=(n+1)^2\cdot \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-\sum_{r=1}^n \frac {r(r+1)(2r+1)}6\cdot (2r+1)$$
but again this does not seem to get us any further.

---

**1st Edit**

Putting $T_m=\sum_{r=1}^n r^m$, the original problem can be restated as an attempt to prove that

$$5T_4=(6T_1-1)T_2$$

---

**2nd Edit**

This [paper](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Beardon201-213.pdf) might be useful.

In section 4 (p$206$), it is stated that 
$$\frac{\sigma_4}{\sigma_2}=\frac {6\sigma_1-1}5$$
which is derived from the Faulhabner polynomials.
$\sigma_m$ has the same definition as our $T_m$ as defined above.

Answer (score 3):

Statement we'd like to show:
$$
\sum^{n}_{r=1}r^4=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}{5}\sum^{n}_{r=1}r^2
$$
Or equivalently:
$$
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=(3n^2+3n-1)\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2
$$

We may recall one of approaches how to get closed form of this expression and utilize it in a slightly different way.
$$
\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^5 + (n+1)^5=\sum^{n}_{r=0}(r+1)^5\\
(r+1)^5=r^5+5r^4+10r^3+10r^2+5r+1
$$
Which leads to:
$$
(n+1)^5=5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4+10\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^3+10\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2+5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r+\sum^{n}_{r=0}1
$$
Similar actions give us:
$$
(n+1)^4=4\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^3+6\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2+4\sum^{n}_{r=0}r+\sum^{n}_{r=0}1\\
(n+1)^3=3\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2+3\sum^{n}_{r=0}r+\sum^{n}_{r=0}1
$$
So let us combine it:
$$
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=(n+1)^5-\left(10\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^3+10\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2+5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r+\sum^{n}_{r=0}1\right)\to\\
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=(n+1)^5-\left(\frac{5}{2}(n+1)^4-5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2-5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r-\frac{3}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}1\right)\to\\
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=(n+1)^5-\left(\frac{5}{2}(n+1)^4-\frac{3}{2}(n+1)^3-\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}r\right)\to\\
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=n(n+1)^3\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}r+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2
$$
At this point we have to express $\sum^{n}_{r=0} r=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which after some simplifications leads us to:
$$
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=3\left(n^2+n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2
$$
We recognize $\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, and finish with:
$$
5\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^4=(3n^2+3n-1)\sum^{n}_{r=0}r^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution! (+1)