# Envisioning (1³ + ... + n³) = (1 + ... + n)²

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to geomtrically visualize the identity (1³ + 2³ + ... + n³) = (1 + 2 + ... + n)², n ∈ ℕ? Are there any other similar identities?

Comment: Have you proven the identity you reference, or seen its proof? (It, indeed, holds, e.g. [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/188588/9003).

Comment: As for a geometric visualization [see AOPS](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Proofs_without_words).  Once there, scroll down until you see 
*Nichomauss' Theorem*.  Also see the applet [here](http://usamts.org/Gallery/G_Gallery.php)

Comment: David: My pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice explanation and diagram on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number).

Another similar identity is found in the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949881/sum-of-fourth-powers-in-terms-of-sum-of-squares)

$$\sigma_4=\sigma_2\frac{6\sigma_1-1}5$$
where $\sigma_m=\sum_{r=1}^n r^m$.

There are more. These can be found in the paper [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Beardon201-213.pdf).

But none as neat as the sum of cubes being the square of the sum of integers. :)