# The sum of series $1\cdot 3\cdot 2^2+2\cdot 4\cdot 3^2+3\cdot 5\cdot 4^2+\cdots \cdots n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of series $1\cdot 3\cdot 2^2+2\cdot 4\cdot 3^2+3\cdot 5\cdot 4^2+\cdots \cdots n$ terms

i have calculate $a_{k} = k(k+2)(k+1)^2$

so $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{k} = \sum^{n}_{k=1}k(k+1)^2(k+2)$

i wan,t be able go further, could some help me with this, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint :

Since we have
$$(k+3)(k+4)-(k-2)(k-1)=10k+10$$
$$\implies \frac{(k+3)(k+4)-(k-2)(k-1)}{10}=k+1$$
we get
$$\begin{align}k(k+2)(k+1)^2&=k(k+1)(k+2)\color{red}{(k+1)}\\\\&=k(k+1)(k+2)\cdot\color{red}{\frac{1}{10}((k+3)(k+4)-(k-2)(k-1))}\\\\&=\frac{1}{10}(k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)-(k-2)(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2))\\\\&=\frac1{10}(a_{k+4}-a_{k+2})\end{align}$$ where $$a_k=k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)(k-4)$$
Now simplify your sum using the idea of [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: +1. Added an explanation at the end, if you do not like it please erase it.

Comment: @Did: I like it. Thanks.

Comment: @mathlove from where did the idea of rewriting $k+1$ come from? Some exercise you did? Inspiration?

Comment: @RSerrao: You can start from what you want to have. The form we want to have is something like $$k(k+1)(k+2)(k+1)=C(f(k)k(k+1)(k+2)-g(k)k(k+1)(k+2))$$where $f(k)=(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)\cdots, g(k)=(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdots$ with a constant $C$. Dividing the both sides by $k(k+1)(k+2)$ gives $$k+1=C(f(k)-g(k))$$ Since the degree of the LHS is $1$, the degree of both $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ has to be $2$. So we are happy if we can have $$k+1=C((k+3)(k+4)-(k-1)(k-2))$$ which indeed holds for $C=1/10$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

Observe that
\begin{align*}
a_k&=k(k+2)(k+1)^2\\
&=(k+1-1)(k+1+1)(k+1)^2\\
&=\left[(k+1)^2-1\right](k+1)^2\\
&=(k+1)^4-(k+1)^2
\end{align*}

Now, here is something that can be useful in order to compute the sum of the fourth powers and squares

[Geometric interpretation for sum of fourth powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241760/geometric-interpretation-for-sum-of-fourth-powers)