# Prove $ \frac{0}{N} + \frac{1}{N} + \ldots + \frac{q-1}{N} =\frac{q(q-1)}{2N}$

Tags: calculus

Why this equation holds? Is that by definition from a well known serie?

$$ \frac{0}{N} + \frac{1}{N} + \ldots + \frac{q-1}{N} =\frac{q(q-1)}{2N}$$

Comment: $1+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$

Comment: Looks like an arithmetic sequence to me. Looks like there's an obvious simplification too: factor out the common term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have
$$
\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N}+\cdots+\frac{q-1}{N}=\frac{1}{N}\left(1+2+\cdots +(q-1)\right),
$$
and then we use that (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn))
$$
1+2+\cdots + (q-1)=\frac{(q-1)q}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is a result of the following:
$1+2+3...+n=\frac12n(n+1)$

We can prove this by considering,
$k^2-(k-1)^2=2k-1$
and taking the sum of both sides.