# Use mathematical induction to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i+4)=n^2+5n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

> Prove:
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i+4)=n^2+5n \textrm{ for each positive integer } n
> $$

So I'm not exactly sure how to do this problem for my math class. Can any mathematicians out there help me? Explaining how to do it is good. I should be able to do the rest once I have the first one figured out. Thank you!

Comment: You should write this task here, no paste picture. It is hard to read. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: They are really quite different from each other. Your 20a is an arithmetic progression, $n$ terms, common difference $2$.You can also solve it by noting that the sum is $2(1+\cdots+n)+4n$. Now if you know the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, you are close to the end.

Comment: For the part with $i$, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260/147263)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by standard induction; consider the sequence of statements
$$
P(n){:}\qquad \sum_{i=1}^n(2i+4)=n^2+5n
$$
Then $P(1)$ reads $2\cdot 1+4=1^2+5\cdot1$ which is true.

Suppose $P(n)$ holds; then you want to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i+4)=(n+1)^2+5(n+1)=n^2+7n+6
$$
By assumption, $\sum_{i=1}^n(2i+4)=n^2+5n$, so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i+4)=
\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i+4)\biggr)+(2(n+1)+4)=
n^2+5n+2n+2+4=n^2+7n+6
$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint- break up the series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2i + 4) = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 4$$

Have you already shown that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$? Then you can note that $2n(n+1)/2 = n(n+1)$. And then you have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 4 = 4n$. And so you get $n^{2} + n + 4n = n^{2} + 5n$.

If you haven't already shown that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = n(n+1)/2$, do that by induction. Then the rest of your proof comes from breaking terms up and factoring.