# Proof By Induction of a Sum

Tags: summation

Can someone look at my proof. I am supposed to prove by induction. The question is to prove the following:

$$\sum _{i=0}^{n}{i} =\frac { n\left( n+1 \right)  }{ 2 } .$$

If $n=1$  Then

$$1=\sum_{i=1}^1{i}=\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=1$$

Now assume $n=k$.  Thus

$$\sum_{i=1}^k{i}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=1$$

If now $n=k+1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^k{i}+(k+1)= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$

Is there anything more that I have to do, or is this it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Should use induction hypothesis to prove equation of last line. Also, the second statement $\sum_1^k i=\cdots=1$ is puzzling. I would say that only the base case has been dealt with.

Comment: Not a duplicate, since OP asks whether a specific "proof" is adequate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So should I delete the 1. And so how can I show the inductive step now?

Answer (score 1):

You've got it.  Some might pick a nit saying that you forgot to say that this shows that the proposition is true for $n=k+1$, thus establishing induction.  But I would give full credit for your proof.

Comment: @MarkFichler Should I remove the 1 which I set equal to in n=k?

Comment: In grading I would certainly pick a nit, and would assume, if there is no external evidence to the contrary, that there is confusion about the induction process.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So how can I clearly show it?

Comment: The problem has been done on MSE several times. Look it up, and at the minimum follow the suggestions of kingW3 and snowball.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the statement is true for $n=k$. In other words, assuming
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$
is true. I don't know why you set it to $1$ when $n=k$. I assume that it's a typo. Next, we'll prove that the statement is true for $n=k+1$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{i}=
\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i}+(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+(k+1)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}
$$
where you use the assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. Then you're done, because this is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add the middle equality to the last line,so it's clear that you used the assumption $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}i+(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+(k+1)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$
Other than that everything is ok.

Comment: I would prefer a bit more algebra to make that final equality. I know it's true, but it could be unwrapped a bit more.