# How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{j = i+1}^{n-1} j $?

Tags: summation

How would I go about solving this summation?

$$\sum\limits_{j = i+1}^{n-1} j $$

---

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this summation using the fact that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k} i= \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

The answer I get with my Ti-89 is $-\frac{i^2}{2}-\frac{-i}{2}+\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: You have $i$ and $n$ in the sum, but $k$ in the answer. Please edit. To get $k(k+1)/2$, the sum should be from $1$ to $k$.

Comment: sorry, I miscommunicated that, i'm going to edit it.

Comment: Also, there's a chance your question is a duplicate of [Proof for formula for sum of sequence 1+2+3+…+n](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260)

Comment: Well it's for my algorithms class and i'm trying to solve a nested summation and we havn't done anything like this in class where we have the lower limit as such

Answer (score 4):

$$1+2+...+i+(i+1)+...+(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)n}2\\
\frac{i(i+1)}2+(i+1)+...+(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)n}2\\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j=\frac12((n-1)n-i(i+1))$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n$ is greater than $i$, we have
$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j-\sum_{j=1}^i j=\binom{n}{2}-\binom{i+1}{2}.$$