# Find and prove a formula for $\|u\|$ where $u = [\sqrt 1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \ldots, \sqrt n]^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried using induction:

Let $x =[\sqrt 1, \sqrt 2]$. Then by Pythagoras $\|x\| = \sqrt 3$. 
Suppose $\|u\|$ is defined for $u$ in $\mathbb R^{\sqrt n}$. Then $\|u\| = \sqrt{1 + 2 + 3 + … + n}$.  Since the length is defined for $\mathbb R^2$, $\|y\| = \sqrt{(1 + 2 + 3 + … + n) + (n + 1)}$ is well-defined. But that's the length of $u$.

Please, check and see what I need to do to fix/improve it. Thanks.

edit:

$u \in \mathbb R^n.$

Length in $\mathbb R^2$ is given by Pythagoras.

$\|u\|$ is well-defined by definition of length.

Comment: $u$ in $\mathbb R^{\sqrt n}$? – The length/dimension of the vector $u$ is $n$, not $\sqrt n$.

Comment: It seems like you have the main idea (i.e. the expression for $\|u\|$), but a lot of what you've written doesn't make sense.  What is $\Bbb R^{\sqrt n}$?  What do you mean by "suppose $\|u\|$ is defined"?  What do you mean by "since length is defined for $\Bbb R^2$?"  What do you mean by $\|y\| = \cdots$ "is well-defined"?  It reads like a mathematical word salad.

Comment: I edited my OP.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lVert u \rVert^2 
= \lVert u \rVert_2^2 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\sqrt{i})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n i \\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align}
So we get
$$
\lVert u \rVert = \sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you. How can I redo it by induction?

Comment: You might prove that equation $(*)$ for the sum of the first $n$ numbers by induction.

Comment: This is perfect. I see the whole picture now. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to ask: what does the subscript $2$ mean in $\|u\|^2_2$?

Comment: There is a family of norms called $p$-norm: $\lVert u \rVert_p = (\sum u_i^p)^{1/p}$. The Euclidean norm is the case $p = 2$.