# Simplify the subtraction of two summations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2 +1) $$

I thought I would use the distributive rule but the question stipulates that my answer should not include a summation sign...

Comment: For every term the two sums have in common, you get a $3$. Then there are two terms left over. This is why you don't need a summation sign

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2 +1) & =\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=1}^n (3(j+1)^2 +1) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2+6j+4) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[(3i^2 +4) - (3i^2+6i+4)\right] \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n -6i \\
& = -6\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2 +1) & =-3n(n+1) \\
\end{align}$$

---

Method 2:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2 +1) & = 7+\sum_{i=2}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^n (3j^2 +1)-3(n+1)^2-1 \\
& =6-3(n+1)^2+\sum_{i=2}^n \left[(3i^2 +4) - (3i^2 +1)\right] \\
& =6-3(n+1)^2+\sum_{i=2}^n3 \\
& =6-3(n+1)^2+\underbrace{3+3+3+\dots+3}_{n-1} \\
& =6-3(n+1)^2+3(n-1) \\
& =-3n^2-3n \\
\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2 +4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2 +1) & =-3n(n+1) \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is nice, +1, but it's more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain conceptually the leap from summation to simple equation. I think I understand: Since i is just a place holder and the first sum is n and the second n+1 and it becomes all over 2 since it's subtraction, then why do you multiple n & n+1.

Comment: How so? I'm really trying to understand these conceptually and not just mathematically.

Comment: @SunshineTS It is the result of $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$, which has interesting proofs.

Comment: @SunshineTS What do you mean "conceptually"?  I'll happily expand my answer based on what you want.

Comment: Appreciate it. $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ Where does this come from? I think I am just confusnig sums and sets in my head.

Comment: @SunshineTS I updated the answer to include MattSamuel's insights, and $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ proof can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn

Comment: Thanks. The proof helped a lot.

Comment: @SunshineTS Always a pleasure ;D