# Proof for formula for sum of sequence $3 + 9 + 27 + 81...+ 3^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

Trying to formulate a proof for that sequence as practice. After reading [this question's answer and lecture on this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn), I decided to try and practice with this sequence.
My try:

Base case $n = 1$

$S(n) = 3^n $

Induction step

$S(n+1) = 3^{n+1}$

Then

$Sn + n+1 = S(n+1)$

Comment: You can use $ a^n -1 = (a-1)(1+a^2+a^3+...+a^{n-1}) $

Comment: Are you required to use induction? Regardless your answer is incorrect. The sum is not equal to $3^n$. This is in fact the $n^{th}$ term. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n\ 3^k = \frac{3}{2}\left(3^{n}-1\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\require{cancel}S & =3+9+27+\dots3^n \\
3S & =3(3+9+27+\dots3^n) \\
& = 9+27+81+\dots3^{n+1} \\
\hline S-3 & =(3+9+27+\dots3^n)-3 \\
& = 9+27+\dots3^n \\
\hline 3S-(S-3) & = \left(\color{blue}{9+27+\dots3^n}+3^{n+1}\right)-\left(\color{blue}{9+27+\dots3^n}\right) \\
2S+3 & = \left(\xcancel{9+27+\dots3^n}+3^{n+1}\right)-\left(\xcancel{9+27+\dots3^n}\right) \\
2S+3 & = 3^{n+1} \\
2S & = 3^{n+1}-3 \\
S & = \frac12\left(3^{n+1}-3\right)
\end{align}$$

---

> $$3+9+27+\dots3^n=\frac12\left(3^{n+1}-3\right)$$