# Prove the identity combinatorially $\sum^{n-1}_{i=1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

I know the RHS is ${n}\choose 2$ and I'm suppose to think to the LHS as a pair but I'm not sure how exactly I'm suppose to decomposition it

Comment: See also this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2310/9464

Answer (score 1):

You’re counting $2$-element subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. The righthand side counts them all at once. The $i$-th term on the lefthand side counts the number of pairs having $i$ as larger member.

Answer (score 0):

Recall Pascal's triangle and the Hockey-stick identity to sum along the $1+2+3+\dots+n$ diagonal.