# Limit proof for infinite sum equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So I apparently found this doodling around, can anyone prove it?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^x i }{x}}=2$$

Comment: Please take the time to type out the question.  Thank you.

Comment: If only I knew how to do it... first time posting here

Comment: =D please check the [handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) then!  And welcome to the site!

Comment: I honestly can't understand the limit though.  Too many fractions, can you make it more clear?

Comment: Not only either typing or pasting: put the image straight!

Comment: Its the limit as x approaches infinity of x over (the  sum from 1 to x) over x

Comment: DonAntonio, 10 reputation required for that

Comment: Yet trying to learn the way to type it in tho

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn

Comment: @Otermeram try viewing my edit to learn a bit of the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be:

$$\cfrac x{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^x i}x}=\frac{x^2}{\frac{x(x+1)}2}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac1{\frac12}=2$$

Comment: That's really neat. I haven't studied calculus at university yet but I do understand the concept of limits, but since I don't know how to simplify sums and other stuff I couldn't realise about it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the link I sent