# Sum of all the digits from 1 to 10000

Tags: arithmetic

I need to add up all the digits in the numbers $1$ to $10000$. How would I do that without using a calculator?

I don't get it one bit. We are doing something in our math class about this.

Comment: 10000*10001/2 = 50005000

Comment: can you do 1 through 10? is there a pattern?

Comment: @Kaynex: all the _digits_, not all the numbers.

Comment: Is the question about the sum of all the **numbers** or the sum of all the **digits** in the numbers ?

Comment: @trueblueanil it appears to be digits, because it says "add up all the digits in the numbers 1 - 1000".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it we are not told to sum up all the numbers from $1$ to $10\,000$ but the decimal digits of these numbers. Taking the numbers from $0000$ to $9999$ instead we have $10\,000$ numbers having four digits with an average value of $4.5$. The sum of all appearing digits therefore is $10\,000\cdot4\cdot 4.5=180\,000$. Add $1$ to this for the single number $10\,000$, and obtain $180\,001$ as final result.

Comment: Numberphile did a video on this and it looks like they used a similar method to what you outlined. https://youtu.be/Dd81F6-Ar_0

Answer (score 2):

First note that the sum of $0$ through $9$ is $45$. Also note that from $0000$ to $9999$, each digit appears exactly $1000$ times, for each of the $4$ positions. Therefore, the sum of all digits in the numbers $1$ through $10000$ is
$$45\cdot 4\cdot 1000 + 1=180001$$
I hope this helps you intuitively understand.

Comment: How each digit appears 1000 times? e.g. for first position, each digit appear only once.

Answer (score 1):

How many times does a 1 appear in the last digit?  How many times does a 2 appear in the last digit?  Etc.

How many times does a 1 appear in the 10's position?  How many times does a 2 appear in the 10's position?  Etc.

How many times does a 1 appear in the 100's position?  How many times does a 2 appear in the 100's position?  Etc.

How many times does a 1 appear in the 1,000's position?  How many times does a 2 appear in the 1,000's position?  Etc.

How many times does a 1 appear in the 10,000's position?  (Answer: Exactly once.)  How many times does a 2 appear int 10,000's position? (Answer: never.)

Answer those questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Add first all digits up to $9999$.

**Hint 2** Ignore the zeroes.

**Hint 3** Each digit $1-9$ appears how many times in each of the four possible positions?