# How to find the sum of $(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to have a short way to find the sum of $(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11)$, so is here any short way to sum these numbers?
thanks in advance

Comment: These are [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: If you don't know the general "Gaussian" trick, you might nonetheless notice that lots of pairs sum to $10$, i.e., $(1+9)+(2+8)+(3+7)+(4+6)+5+10+11=40+5+10+11=66$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very famous identity.

$$1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Your case would be $n=11$.

As a simple proof, you can consider twice the value, and group the terms:

$$2[1+2+...+(n-1)+n]=\begin{matrix}
&[1&+&2&+&...&+&(n-1)&+&n]\\
+&[1&+&2&+&...&+&(n-1)&+&n]
\end{matrix}$$

Which we can rearrange.

$$2[1+2+...+(n-1)+n]=\begin{matrix}
&[1&+&2&+&...&+&(n-1)&+&n]\\
+&[n&+&(n-1)&+&...&+&2&+&1]
\end{matrix}$$

Now, we can add elements vertically, noticing that each sum is $n+1$

$$2[1+2+...+(n-1)+n]=[(n+1)+(n+1)+...+(n+1)]$$

since there are n terms:

$$2[1+2+...+(n-1)+n]=n(n+1)$$

$$1+2+...+(n-1)+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Comment: Thanks sir..!! but I want shorter than this one, does it exist?

Comment: What do you mean by shorter?!  Add $n$ and its square, then multiply by a half.  Two multiplications and an addition.  What could be shorter?

Comment: so what about this formula ( middle number * last number = answer ). (6*11=66)

Comment: @DietrichBurde, here we have: n=11, m=6

Comment: @XanderHenderson no. It doesn't get shorter. This is it.

Comment: @ZiaurhmanZia When $n$ is even, the "middle number" is not an integer. E.g., $1+2+3+4=\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}=10$ and $2.5\cdot 4=10$.

Answer (score 2):

One time write the numbers by the usuall order 
and one time in the reverse order; 
and then add them together :

$$\underbrace {\begin {array} {ccccccccccc} 
 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\ 
 11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\ \hline  
12&12&12&12&12&12&12&12&12&12&12&
\\  \end {array}}_{11-times}$$

---

So "twice your sum" is equal to $11.12$;

So "your sum" is equal to $\dfrac{11.12}{2}$.

Comment: @ user236182 ,Yes you are right.

Comment: you''re right but how about this formula ( the middle number * last number = answer ). (6*11=66)

Comment: @ Ziaurhman Zia See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn

Comment: @ZiaurhmanZia When $n$ is even, the "middle number" is not an integer. E.g., $1+2+3+4=\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}=10$ and $2.5\cdot 4=10$.