# Compute the values of the Double Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, telescopic-series

Compute the value of the following double sum:

$$\sum_{\mu=1}^n\sum_{\upsilon=\mu+1}^n\frac{\mu^2}{\upsilon(2\upsilon-1)}$$

I started by simply trying to compute the value of the inner sum:

$$\sum_{\upsilon=\mu+1}^n\frac{\mu^2}{\upsilon(2\upsilon-1)}$$

treating $\mu$ as a generic constant.  I can pull it out and do partial fraction decomposition to see if that helps:

$$\mu^2\sum_{\upsilon=\mu+1}^n\left[\frac{2}{2\upsilon-1}-\frac{1}{\upsilon}\right]$$

But this doesn't really seem to get me very far.  I feel pretty stuck at this point.  How would you evaluate this sum?

Answer (score 1):

By exchanging the two sums we get
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu=1}^n\sum_{\upsilon=\mu+1}^n\frac{\mu^2}{\upsilon(2\upsilon-1)}&=\sum_{\upsilon=2}^n\frac{1}{\upsilon(2\upsilon-1)}\sum_{\mu=1}^{\nu-1}\mu^2\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{\upsilon=2}^n\frac{\nu(\nu-1)(2\upsilon-1)}{\upsilon(2\upsilon-1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{\upsilon=2}^n( \nu-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{12}\end{align}$$
where we used [Sum of First $n$ Squares Equals $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16) and then [Proof for formula for sum of sequence $1+2+3+\ldots+n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn)