# Nested summation - intuition

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, summation, alternative-proof

To begin with, I noted that

$$ \begin{aligned} \displaystyle \sum_{r_1 = 1}^{r} r_1 &= \dfrac{1}{2} r (r+1) \quad &(1)\\ \displaystyle \sum_{r_2 = 1}^{r} \displaystyle \sum_{r_1 = 1}^{r_2} r_1 &= \dfrac{1}{6} r (r+1) (r+2). & \qquad(2) \end{aligned}$$ This led me to suggest the more general conjecture that $$ \begin{aligned} \displaystyle \sum_{r_n = 1}^{r} \displaystyle \sum_{r_{n-1} = 1}^{r_n} \cdots \displaystyle \sum_{r_2 = 1}^{r_3} \displaystyle \sum_{r_1 = 1}^{r_2} r_1 &= \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!} \prod_{k=0}^{n} (r+k) \\ &= \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!} \dfrac{(r+n)!}{(r-1)!} \qquad(\star)  \end{aligned} $$

I believe that I've managed to successfully prove this using induction, but on the whole the process isn't very enlightening and given how "nice" the result is I'm led to believe that there's some more general insight here that I'm missing.

I've seen a link to the [geometric interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn/2028238#2028238) of $ (1) $ by "pasting together" two copies of the sum to form a rectangle and I imagine the proof carries through analogously for $ (2) $ by forming a cuboid using 6 copies of the summation, but I'm not sure how to formalise this method of thinking (or indeed how to generalise it to higher dimensions). Of course this is just one particular thought I've had so any alternative proofs would also be welcome!

Comment: Note that $(\star)={r+n\choose n+1}$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I used this step in my inductive proof but still couldn't spot an obvious connection between the binomial coefficient and the nested summation

Comment: Geometrically, it can be related to the volume of a simplex: the triangle spanned by the origin and the two basis vectors in two dimensions; the pyramid spanned by the origin and the three basis vectors in three dimensions; and so forth.  Each of these simplices constitutes $1/d!$ of the square/cube/hypercube, where $d$ is the dimension; the fact that we have a binomial coefficient rather than a straight power of $r$ comes about because we're counting discrete objects, rather than continuous volume.  Arnaud Mortier's answer contains (or links to) the relevant details.

Comment: @BrianTung This elucidates the geometric approach I was considering but would this suffice as a proof? This then raises the question of how we know d! d-simplices tile a d-dimensional hypercube but I don't have enough familiarity with these structures to follow up with something like that. Since it's related to volume does that mean we could think of this as a sort of discrete integral?

Comment: @backstrapp: No, I would not say it would suffice as a proof—it's not the same situation, in the first place, and in the second place, we would need demonstrations of the various assertions.  I was intending only to give some of the geometrical intuition, in case you or other readers were wondering. // You could indeed think of it as a kind of discrete integral, though I'm not sure I can make out a quick way of seeing the discrete correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The essence is already encoded in the indices of the sums.

> We can write for positive integer $r$ the sums as
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r_n=1}^r\sum_{r_{n-1}=1}^{r_n}\cdots\sum_{r_1=1}^{r_2}r_1\tag{1}
> &=\sum_{r_n=1}^r\sum_{r_{n-1}=1}^{r_n}\cdots\sum_{r_1=1}^{r_2}\sum_{r_0=1}^{r_1}1\\
> &=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq r_0\leq r_1\leq \cdots\leq r_n\leq r}} 1\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The number of summands given by the index range $$1\leq r_0\leq r_1\leq \cdots\leq r_n\leq r$$  is the number of ordered $(n+1)$-tupel $(r_0,\ldots,r_n)$ between $1$ and $r$ with repetition. This number is given by the binomial coefficient
\begin{align*}
\binom{(n+1)+r-1}{n+1}=\binom{n+r}{n+1}
\end{align*}
which corresponds to ($\star$) in OP's post.

Comment: Thanks, I think that it was the step in which you collapsed the nested summations into a single one that I was missing (as well as the corresponding change in the limits)

Comment: @backstrapp: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 4):

These numbers are called [Simplicial polytopic numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers).

$(1)$ corresponds to triangular numbers, $(2)$ to tetrahedral numbers, and so on. The relation with binomial coefficients and in fact to the whole Pascal triangle is well known.

Answer (score 1):

We start off with a basic identity which can be proven combinatorially, namely
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\tag{1}.
$$
Indeed the RHS counts the number of $k+1$ element subsets of $\{0,1\dotsc,n\}$. The LHS counts the same thing by classifying the subsets based on their maximum element. For $0\leq i\leq n$, there are $\binom{i}{k}$ subsets of $\{0,1\dotsc,n\}$ of length $k+1$ whose maximum element is $i$. Then for example
$$
\sum_{r_2=1}^r\sum_{r_{1}=1}^{r_{2}}\binom{r_{1}}{1}=\sum_{r_2=1}^r\binom{r_{2}+1}{2}=\binom{r+2}{3}
$$
and can easily be generalized, indeed,
$$
\sum_{r_n=1}^r\sum_{r_{n-1}=1}^{r_{n}}\dotsb\sum_{r_{1}=1}^{r_{2}}\binom{r_{1}}{1}=\binom{r+n}{n+1}.
$$
Another way to see the same result is to observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r_n=1}^r\sum_{r_{n-1}=1}^{r_{n}}\dotsb\sum_{r_{1}=1}^{r_{2}}r_{1}
&=[z^{r}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}}\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\\
&=[z^r]\frac{z}{(1-z)^{n+2}}\\
&=[z^{r-1}](1-z)^{-(n+2)}\\
&=\binom{r+n}{r-1}
\end{align}
$$
where $[z^m]$ extracts the coefficient of $z^m$ from the generating function. Here we have used the result that if $A(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}z^n$ is the generating function corresponding to the sequence $(a_n)$ then the generating function corresponding to the sequence of partial sums is given by
$$
\frac{A(z)}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}
\right)z^n.
$$

Comment: Very interesting, along with the approach suggested by Markus Scheuer the counting argument in the first identity is a lot clearer! I'm not too familiar with generating functions so was wondering how you arrived at the alternative method however?