# What does the sum of all the numerals from the numbers from $100$ up to $1000$ equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

What does the sum of all the numerals from the numbers from $100$ up to $1000$ equal to?

Comment: Hint: $100 + \ldots + 1000 = (100 + 1000) + (101 + 999) + \ldots + (549+551) + 550$.

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this by using the following formula:

$\sum^n_{i=1}i=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

The proof of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn). If we rephrase your question in mathematical terms, using this sum notation, you are asking:

$\sum^{1000}_{i=100}i=?$

This is equal to

$\sum^{1000}_{i=1}i-\sum^{99}_{i=1}i$

So use the formula above with these values to get the answer.