# How to find the formula given here (NOT PROOF)

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm studying computer science, but my maths is a little lacking, and my course material isn't being explicit about how things are calculated (they expect you to just know).

Given a sequence such as:

```
(n − 1) + (n − 2) + ⋯ + 1
```

That results in the formula (if that's even the correct term?):

```
½n^2 − ½n
```

So:

```
(n − 1) + (n − 2) + ⋯ + 1 = ½n^2 − ½n
```

How do I work out what that formula(?) is?

What is that type of maths called?

I'm at a real loss... Without having any direction, it's nearly impossible to Google for a solution.

UPDATE:

So if I only had:

```
(n − 1) + (n − 2) + ⋯ + 1
```

How would I work out what the formula would be?

Comment: These are called [Triangular Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is an example of [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not really interested in what the number sequence is, more how the formula is derived? So, why `1/2n^2 - 1/2n` is the answer, and what process was taken to discover it..... I can work out the sequence, and how it will end, but I'm at a loss how to convert that sequence in to something like `1/2n^2 - 1/2n`.... That's the process I'm trying to identify to study further.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn) is the proof of the formula for sum of sequence $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$. Simply subtract $n$ from the formula to get the sum for sequence $1 + 2 + \cdots + n - 1$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - Would I be right in thinking that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy_L8tnihDM - Is showing how to work through this?

Comment: Yes, your example is a special case where the first term and the difference between terms are $1$

Comment: My understanding is for these sorts of problems you have to just guess the formula. There's no systematic way to derive it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You could use the following trick to obtain the formula:
\begin{matrix}
(n − 1) &+& (n − 2) &+& \dotsm &+& 1 \\
1 &+& 2 &+&\dotsm &+& (n − 1) \\
\hline
n &+& n &+& \dotsm &+& n
\end{matrix}