# Why is the $\sum _{k = 1}^{\infty }\frac{2k^2+3}{k} = (n + 1)n + 3H_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I have an infinite arithmetic series whose terms are expressed as $$\sum _{k = 1}^{\infty }\frac{2k^2+3}{k} $$ and the sum of it is equal to $$(n + 1)n + 3H_n$$ I can't wrap my head around how they got to this answer.

Comment: In the title you have the sum going to infinity.  In the result of the summation you have $n$'s appearing.  In any event, you should try to make an attempt to format this with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if possible.

Comment: On to the math involved here... recall that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i$, so you can split your sum into two.  The first sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{2i^2}{i}$ simplifies to $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i$ which you should recognize is twice the $n$'th triangular number and so $(n+1)n$.  The second part $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{3}{i}=3\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i}$ is $3H_n$ by definition of $H_n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, this largely answers my question. I still don't understand, however, why 2 sum(i = 1 to n) i is equal to (n+1)n. Is there a general formula for solving these kind of problems?

Comment: [Proof $1+2+3+4+\dots+n = \frac{n\times (n+1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-1234-cdotsn-fracn-timesn12)

Comment: @JMoravitz Is it usual procedure to provide a full answer to questions like this, or just a hint towards the first step? Because my approach is to offer OP the first step, or a hint towards the insight needed, or whatever. (Plus I'm too lazy to plod through all the details, that's OP's job.)

Answer (score 1):

Given the confusion regarding what the question is actually saying (is it going to infinity or to $n$?) and the inclarity based on the formatting of the expression, all I will do is offer a clue.

Try separating the expression in brackets into two separate summations: one of $\dfrac {2 i^2} i = 2i$ and one of $\dfrac 3 i$.

You will find it's a lot simpler than it looked at first.