# Solving $1+2+3+4+ \cdots+ n=$n(n+1)/2)$ $through use of binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to understand proofs of the $1+2+3+4+ \cdots$ series.

I'm puzzled by the 3rd point of this post where it is solved by binomial coefficient

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2288/777575

He equates ${n+1 \choose 2}= \frac 12 n(n+1)$ such pairs. Which is true, but 
what I am confused about is how did he arrive at $\frac 12 n(n+1)$ based on the info of the post: is there a way that I am not seeing?

I'm not talking about reaching the formula through other methods not relevant to how it is solved in the post eg square numbers divided by $2$ etc.

Comment: Do you wonder why ${n+1 \choose 2}=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ or why $1+2+\ldots+n={n+1 \choose 2}$?

Comment: @A.Γ.
The former!!!

Comment: Isn't it just by the definition? $${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ Ther are lots of cancelations here.

Comment: What I am asking is how did he get 1/2(n)(n+1) from (n+1) choose 2, it does not make sense to me

Comment: To determine the yellow disc, you pick two blue discs. You can choose 2 blue discs in $n+1 \choose 2$ ways

Comment: $${n+1\choose 2}=\frac{(n+1)!}{2!(n+1-2)!}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}{2\cdot 1\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}.$$

Comment: @A.Γ.
Thanks 
Wow I was confused I had thought n+1 could not be factorialed

Comment: Yes,it happens to everybody, no problem. Glad it helped.

Comment: $\dbinom{n}{2}$ counts the number of $2$-element subsets of a $n$-element set. 

We can count them: Say our set is $\{1,\dots,n\}$. 

The $2$-subsets are $\underbrace{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\dots,\{1,n\}}_{(n-1)}$ and $\underbrace{\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\dots,\{2,n\}}_{(n-2)}$ and $\underbrace{\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\dots,\{3,n\}}_{(n-3)}$ and $\dots$ and finally $\underbrace{\{n-1,n\}}_1$. 

That is, there are: 

$$\dbinom{n}{2}=(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+\dots+(n-n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Many such subsets.