# History behind "Rainbow" Addition Facts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

While trying to solve a chiming clock problem algebraically, I came across a solution which used "Rainbow" Addition Facts.

**Problem**

*An old chime clock strikes one chime at 1 o’clock, two chimes at 2 o’clock, three
chimes at 3 o’clock and so on. How many chimes will it strike in a 12-hour cycle?*

**Solution**

[image]

To be honest, It's my first encounter with "Rainbow" Addition Facts and it looked so alien to me at first.

Couldn't find any information regarding "Rainbow" Addition Facts on Internet other than couple YouTube videos which shows how to use them.

I'd hear about history of "Rainbow" Addition Facts and theory behind it.

Comment: Your question is better suited at [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) or [Maths Educators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what are "Rainbow" Addition Facts?

Comment: @TobyMak, I didn't know existence of such specific meta QAs. I searched here on this Math meta for "History" keyword and found lot of questions. I thought it's okay to ask. Again, I welcome if someone can merge this Question to appropriate place

Comment: You can always delete your question and ask on one of these sites. It would be good if you can explain what they are and give an example, such as $1 + 9 = 2 + 8 = 3 + 7 = 10$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Complicated but only handful resources out there with information about it. It does the job nicely but I don't have enough confidence to use it in practice.

Comment: @TobyMak Please see my edit.

Comment: That's much better than before. It seems like you want to know why $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$: there are plenty of resources that address this online (such as a picture proof with stones).

Comment: Similar to Gauss' story from his childhood to add up $1+2+3+\cdots+100$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as an abstract duplicate of [Prove $1+2+3+4+\cdots+n = \frac{n\times(n+1)}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-1234-cdotsn-fracn-timesn12).

Comment: @TobyMak It doesn't. I need to understand the actual theory behind Rainbow facts. I know your answer as a solution but I really need to understand how Rainbow Facts works by finding common number and getting an answer by multiplying that common number.  For above case, the common number is 13 and it get solution  multiplying  by  6 which is 78.

Comment: This is no different to Gauss's proof (the first answer in the link), where you write the sum backwards and add it to itself, as $1 + n = 2 + (n - 1) = 3 + (n - 2) = \cdots = n + 1$ all add to the same number. The label "rainbow facts" is just a distraction.

Comment: @TobyMak I guess it does but I am looking for more of layman explanation because my head is not suitable for number based proofs. I'm so sorry!

Comment: It's okay. Try to convince yourself of Gauss's proof by trying it with small numbers, such as $4$. Write $1 + 2 + 3 + 4$ and add it to $4 + 3 + 2 + 1$. Complete the proof, and then try it with another number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of "rainbow facts", but it seems to be a very roundabout way of saying that $1+2+3+\cdots+12=78.$

In general, $$1+2+3+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}2,$$

which you can prove by writing the sum twice and pairing elements that add to $n+1$.

Comment: Similar to Gauss' story from his childhood to add up $1+2+3+⋯+100$.

Comment: @Théophile I think Rainbow facts does it differently. It find a common number and multiply that common number. For above example, The common number is 13 and it multiply 13 x 6 which gives 78

Comment: @codespeare Yes. It finds the common sum which is $n+1$ and multiplies it with $n/2$. This is not different from what this answer tells. For your example, $n+1=13$ and $n/2=6$.