# Does generalized master method for solving recurrences work for: $T(n) = T(n - 1) + n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I know that the generalized master method works for recurrences in the form: $T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}) + f(n)$, but does it work for:

$T(n) = T(n - 1) + n$,

where there is constant following n?

Comment: Hint: suppose $T(n) = an^2 +bn+c$ and solve for $a,b,c$

Comment: No, $\log_b a$ is not defined.

Comment: This recurrence it very ... very easy. Don't complicate the things, expand ... [see the pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-1234-cdotsn-fracn-timesn12).