# How is the summation being expanded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am trying to understand summations by solving some example problems, but I could not understand how is the second to last line being expanded? I would really appreciate if you could explain me how is it being expanded.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 =\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j =\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}j - \sum_{j=1}^{i}j\right) =\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right) =\\
&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n^2+n-i^2-i =\\
&\frac{1}{2}\left((n-1)n^2 + (n-1)n - \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2\right) - 
    \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n\right)\right) =\\
&f(n) = \frac{n(n(n+1))}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12} - \frac{n(n+1)}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Which steps more specifically?  Are you comfortable with the idea that if you add three copies of $1$ together that you get a result of $3$?  How about if you add $10$ copies of $1$ to itself, what would that result be?  If you add $j$ copies of $1$ to itself?

Comment: The sum from index $1$ to $n-1$ is the sum from index $1$ to $n$ minus the $n$th term. Then they use Faulhaber's formula to evaluate the sum of first and second powers of first $n$ integers.

Comment: In the second last line why n^2 and n is being subtracted from the from the expansion of i^2 and i.

Comment: Now... how about if you add $n$ copies of $2$ together?  Or if you add $n$ copies of $10$ together?  Or $n$ copies of $j$ together?  What gets more interesting perhaps is when what is being added is not constant.  For that, you should read more about 'triangle sums' or 'pyramidal sums' etc...

Comment: "*Why $n^2$ and $n$ is being subtracted from the from the expansion of $i^2$ and $i$*"  Presumably because the formula they are citing/using was written specifically where the upper bound was $n$ and not $n-1$ and instead of rewriting the formula they just subtracted the last term.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the suggestion, I am pretty new to Mathematics. for sure I will give a read to these topics.

Comment: [Sum of first $n$ squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16/48152#48152) and [sum of first $n$ naturals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-1234-cdotsn-fracn-timesn12)

Comment: Incidentally, a simpler derivation, starting from the second line,
is:
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j =
\sum_{j=2}^n\left(j\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}1\right) =
\sum_{j=2}^nj(j - 1) \\ =
\frac13\sum_{j=2}^n[(j + 1)j(j - 1) - j(j - 1)(j - 2)] =
\frac{n(n^2 - 1)}3.
\end{multline*}

Comment: Here's another derivation that doesn't require much calculation.
I'll denote the number of elements of a finite set $S$ by $\#S.$
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 =
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(n - \sum_{k=j+1}^{n}1\right)
\\ = n \times \#\{\{i, j\} : 1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n\} -
\#\{\{i, j, k\} : 1 \leqslant i < j < k \leqslant n\} \\
= n\binom{n}2 - \binom{n}3 = \frac{n(n - 1)(3n - (n - 2))}6
= \frac{n(n^2 - 1)}3.
\end{multline*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that what has to be explained is this (I've introduced parentheses on the left hand side for clarity):
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(n^2 + n - i^2 - i\right) = \\
(n-1)n^2 + (n-1)n - \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 - n^2\right) - \left(\frac{n(n+1)}2 - n\right).
\end{multline*}
This equation results from adding together the following four identities:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n^2 & = (n - 1)n^2, \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n & = (n - 1)n, \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^ni^2 - n^2 \\ & = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 - n^2, \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i & = \sum_{i=1}^ni - n \\ & = \frac{n(n+1)}2 - n.
\end{align*}
Lines 4 and 6 follow, of course, from the familiar identities:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^ni^2 & = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6, \\
\sum_{i=1}^ni & = \frac{n(n+1)}2.
\end{align*}
I don't know why it was done this way! It seems to me that it would have been simpler just to write:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2 & = \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}6, \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i & = \frac{(n-1)n}2.
\end{align*}
(Also, in the comments, I've suggested two ways to arrive at the final answer with less calculation.)

Comment: I suppose it's just a kind of trick, to get rid of an $n^2$ term and an $n$ term; but if one is going to be tricky about it, there are less laborious ways of evaluating the sum (as I've shown).

Comment: So to change from n-1 to n, we have to subtract the same term from the f(n)? What does this difference mean?

Comment: You've lost me, I'm afraid! The notation $f(n),$ as I understand it, merely denotes the final (but unsimplified) expression for the sum. (It doesn't play any part in the argument, and could be omitted without loss.) I don't know what you mean about "changing" from $n-1$ to $n.$ There is a sum of $n-1$ terms, and a sum of $n$ terms, which differ, of course, by a single term ($n^2$ or $n,$ as the case may be). The calculation is done in an odd way (not one I would ever have chosen, anyway), apparently just to be able to use these $n^2$ and $n$ terms to simplify just one part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from line 4 of the displayed equation, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=(n-1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ because there are $n-1$ equal terms. Also,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i(i+1)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i(i+1)(i+2)}{6}-\frac{(i-1)i(i+1)}{6}\right)$$ is a telescoping sum, hence equal to
$$\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)-0}6.$$
Therefore, the whole sum is equal to
$$
\frac{(n - 1)n(n + 1)}2 - \frac{(n - 1)n(n + 1)}6 = \frac{(n - 1)n(n + 1)}3.
$$

---

The "weird" decomposition above comes in fact from a general property of the raising factorials: e.g.

$$i(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)(i+4)-(i-1)i(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)=5i(i+1)(i+2)(i+3).$$

Comment: The denominator of the final expression should be $3,$ shouldn't it?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: mh, no, why ?

Comment: If you're claiming that the value of the sum in the question is $\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}6$  (your answer isn't clearly enough worded for me to be sure that that's what you're claiming), then try taking $n = 2$ and see if it's right.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: as far as I know, $1=1$. My wording says that the value of the sum ... is such ...

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: please expand the sum to show how you obtain $2$.

Comment: Certainly:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^1\sum_{j=i+1}^2\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 =
\sum_{j=2}^2\sum_{k=1}^{j}1 = \sum_{k=1}^21 = 2.
$$

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: that's the global sum, nowhere mentioned in my answer. Compare to the OP's expansion.

Comment: To save time, I'll edit your answer. If you don't like my edit, you can revert it, so no harm is done.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: I'll leave it as is, but notice that my answer was completely self contained, merely saying $a=b$ and $c=d$, where $a$ and $c$ appeared in the OP.