# In a group, the number of non-self-inverse elements is even

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

The problem I am attempting to prove is the following: In any finite group $G$, the number of elements not equal to their own inverse is an even number.

**Caveat**: I have had very limited experience with proofs. Any comments would be appreciated.

Let $a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}$ be elements of $G$. Since $G$ is a group, every element in $G$ must have an inverse in $G$. Let the inverse of each element be represented by $a_{1}^{-1}, a_{2}^{-1}, ..., a_{n}^{-1}$. An element $a_{k}$ in $G$ that is not equal to its own inverse can be written as $a_{k} \neq a_{k}^{-1}$. For every element $a_{k}$, there is another element $a_{k}^{-1}$ that is not equal to its own inverse denoted by $a_{k}^{-1} \neq a_{k}$. So for every element $a_{k}$ in $G$ whose inverse is not equal to their own inverse, there will be 2 elements in $G$ namely $a_{k}$ and $a_{k}^{-1}$. Let the integer $q$ denote the number of elements ranging from $a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}$ who are not equal to their own inverse. In addition for every value $q$, there must be another element in $a_{1}^{-1}, a_{2}^{-1}, ..., a_{n}^{-1}$ not equal to their own inverse. So the total number of elements not equal to their own inverse can be denoted by 2$q$, which is an even number.

Comment: The idea is right.  There is some inaccuracy in wording.  Your integer $q$ is what has to be shown even. The fact that $2q$ is even doesn't help.  The crucial fact that you must use is the fact that the inverse of $a^{-1}$ is $a$.  Let $Q$ be the set of elements  that are not their own inverse.  If $a$ is such an element, call $b$ the  *partner* of $a$ if $ab=e$. Note that $b$ is the partner of $a$ iff $a$ is the partner of $b$.  So we have divided $Q$ into "couples." This means $Q$ has an even number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The map $\rm n \mapsto n^{-1}$ is a permutation of order 2 so it decomposes into cycles of length 1 or 2. So non-fixed-points are paired with their inverse. This leads to a proof of [Wilson's theorem for groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307/prove-that-n-1-1mod-n-iff-n-is-prime/1865#1865)

An analogous pairing arises for any nontrivial self-inverse map. Such [involutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) are ubiquitous. For example, the involution $\rm\: d \to n/d\:$ on the divisors of $\rm\:n\:$ implies that nonsquare integers have an even number of divisors. Here are some further examples [proofs using  involutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+involution)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to list the elements of $G$ individually. It suffices to bring the essential idea to the fore.

The inversion map $\iota:\>a\mapsto a^{-1}$ is bijective and *involutive*, i.e.,  $\>\iota(a)=b$ implies $\iota(b)=a$. It follows that the set of $a\in G$ with $a\ne\iota(a)$ is the disjoint union of finitely many pairs $\{a,\iota(a)\}$, hence has an even number of elements.