# $(m, m+2)$ is twin prime, iff $4((m-1)! + 1) \equiv -m \pmod {m(m+2)}\ $ [Clement's theorem]

Tags: prime-numbers

The Wiki page on [Twin Primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) says

> The pair $(m, m+2)$ is twin prime, iff $4((m-1)! + 1) \equiv -m \pmod
> {m(m+2)}$.

This is obviously connected to Wilson's Theorem. Can anybody provide a proof for that, along the lines of thought given here,
[Wilson's Theorem/Proofs/Prime modulus – another proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Proofs)?

Comment: Use Chinese Remainder theorem.  If $m$ is odd, then the right condition is equivalent to two formulas: $4((m-1)!+1) \equiv 0 \pmod m$ and $4((m-1)!+1)\equiv -2 \pmod {m+2}$.  The case where $m$ is even needs to be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Wilson's Theorem, if $m$ is prime, then $(m-1)!+1\equiv 0\pmod{m}$, and therefore 
$$4[(m-1)!+1]+m \equiv 0\pmod{m}.\tag{$1$}$$

If $m+2$ is prime, then $(m+1)!+1\equiv 0\pmod{m+2}$, again by Wilson's Theorem. But since $m+1\equiv -1\pmod{m+2}$, and $m\equiv -2\pmod{m+2}$, we have 
$(m+1)!\equiv (-1)(-2)(m-1)!\equiv 2(m-1)!\pmod{m+2}$, and therefore
$$4[(m-1)!+1]+m \equiv 2(m+1)!+2+m+2\equiv 0\pmod{m+2}.\tag{$2$}$$
Since $m$ is odd, the numbers $m$ and $m+2$ are relatively prime, and therefore by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $4[(m-1)!+1]+m\equiv 0\pmod{m(m+2)}$.

The proof of the converse follows similar lines, this time using the fact that the Wilson condition is sufficient for primality.

Comment: Very nice. Not along the lines I asked for, but (even better) I learnt something else. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Follows immediately (*mechanically!*) by W = [Wilson's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865/242) and [(Easy) CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) as below,
using $\!\bmod m\!+\!2\!:\ \color{#0a0}{(m\!+\!1)!^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}}\!\!\! = \smash{\underbrace{(m\!+\!1)m}_{\large \ \ (-1)(-2)}(m\!-\!1)!\equiv \color{#0a0}{2(m\!-\!1)!}}\,\ $ [[Wilson reflection]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24131/242), $ $i.e.

$\begin{align}
   m\!+\!2\ {\rm prime} &\smash{\overset{\small \rm W\!}\iff} \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(m\!+\!1)!}}^{\large\color{#0a0}{2(m-1)!}}\equiv -1\!\!\!\pmod{\!m\!+\!2}\smash{\overset{\color{#0a0}{\times\ 2}}\iff} \color{#0af}{4(m\!-\!1)!}\equiv -2\!\!\!\pmod{\!m\!+\!2}\\[.6em]
   m\ {\rm prime} &\smash{\overset{\small \rm W\!}\iff} (m\!-\!1)!\equiv -1\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\ \ \ \smash{\overset{\times\ 4}\iff}\ \  \underbrace{\color{#0af}{4(m\!-\!1)!}\equiv -4\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\phantom{M}}
\end{align}$

$$\overset{\small \rm CRT}\iff\, \color{#0af}{4(m\!-\!1)!}\equiv -4 + m\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{2}{\color{#c00}m}\bmod m\!+\!2\right]}_{\large \color{#c00}m\ \equiv\ -2}\equiv\,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{-4\!-\!m}\,\ \pmod{\!m(m\!+\!2)}$$

This method generalizes to [prime $k$-tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple).

Comment: Please strive not to reply to "Problem Statement Questions" (PSQs).

Comment: @Aqua The Q&A were posted *a decade ago* - when the site was a very different beast (in  "population" mode, and policies and politics differed radically from nowadays).