# Proof for a prime-generating sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $k$ be a positive integer.

Let $n$ be an integer such that $n=6k-1$

Let $r$ be the remainder of the division of $(n-1)!-n$ by $(n+2)$

Conjecture: if $6k+1$ is prime $r=3k+2$

For example the first 25 values of $r$ are:

${5,8,11,2,17,20,23,2,2,32,35,38,41,2,2,50,53,56,2,2,65,2,71,2,77}$

And we have:

$8+5=13=6(2)+1$
$11+8=19=6(3)+1$
$20+17=37=6(6)+1$
$23+20=43=6(7)+1$
$35+32=67=6(11)+1$
$38+35=73=6(12)+1$
$41+38=79=6(13)+1$
$53+50=103=6(17)+1$
$56+53=109=6(18)+1$

I have already proved that if $6k+1$ is a composite number $r=2$ but I failed to prove this conjecture.

Is it hard to prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not true that $r$ alternates in parity.  The first $25$  values are $\{5, 8, 11, 2, 17, 20, 23, 2, 2, 32, 35, 38, 41, 2, 2, 50, 53, 56, 2, 2, 65, 2, 71, 2, 77\}$.

Comment: eyeballintg the first $500$ values, it does appear to be true that no consecutive values are both odd, but consecutive even values are common.  And not just two consecutive terms, at one point there is a string of $11$ consecutive evens.

Comment: Typo?  Clement's theorem [should be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147957/242) $4[(n-1)!+1]+\color{#c00}n \equiv 0 \pmod {n^2+2n}\ \ $

Comment: @lulu : I state that for a given natural number $n$ such that $2n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod {12}$, $k$ and $r$ are both odd or both even. Bill Dubuque: thanks, I edit.

Comment: I edited because the conjecture seems to be true when $r \ne 2$.

Comment: Based on the comment of lulu I found an interesting thing about the first 25 values of $r$... If we sum two consecutive values of $r$ and when $r \ne 2$, we have a prime number. Is always true?

Comment: No...again, there are long blocks of consecutive even $r$.  And even if you exclude consecutive evens, $25$ occurs as the sum $23+2$.

Comment: Important point:  if you are making a numerical conjecture, test it.  Always.  And not for a couple of values.  Check a lot of values.  For instance, there are lots of small primes so it's very misleading to test conjectures about primes for very small numbers.  Do a proper search.

Comment: I think we do not calculate 23+2 because I supposed $r \ne 2$ for my conjecture. Thanks for your advice I will check my conjecture for larger numbers.

Comment: I suspect that the Wilson theorem would be useful but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 3):

$$n+2=6k+1$$ by Wilson's theorem $$(n+1)!\equiv -1\pmod {n+2}$$ it follows that $$n!\equiv 1\pmod{n+2}$$ and that $$(n-1)!\equiv -(2^{-1})\equiv 3k\pmod {n+2}$$ and $$-n\equiv 2\pmod {n+2}$$ so together we have $$3k+2$$ as the remainder $\blacksquare$

As to the addition chains $$(3k+2)+(3(k+1)+2)=6(k+1)+1$$ so what.