# Proof of Wilsons theorem

Tags: prime-numbers

**How to understand the grouping of integers from $2$ to $p-2$ in the proof af Wilsons theorem?**

[image]

I don't understand how you can group the integers $2$ to $p−2$ into $(p-3)/2$ and next how you become the $2*3*...=1 (mod p)$

Comment: The proof seems perfectly understandable to me, so it would help if you could be a bit more specific about what it is that you find confusing.

Comment: I don't understand how you can group the integers 2 to p−2 into (p-3)/2 and next how you become the 2*3*...=1 (mod p)

Comment: Think about the grouping as a re-arrangement of the terms of the product, so instead of $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots$ we have $x \cdot x^{-1} \cdot y \cdot y^{-1} \dots$.

Comment: For example, $2 \cdot 4$ and $3 \cdot 5$ are both congruent to $1$ mod $7$.  So $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 1 \cdot 6 \equiv (7-1)! \equiv -1~ \text{mod}~{7}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wilson's theorem intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478130/wilsons-theorem-intuition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to illustrate what's happening is to apply the proof to a specific value of $p$.  Take, for example, $p = 11$.

We can solve $2x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ with $x = 6$.  We can solve $3x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ with $x = 4$.  We can solve $5x = 1 \pmod {11}$ with $x \equiv 9$.  We can solve $7x \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ with $x = 8$.

Note that in the above, we have accounted for all numbers from $2$ to $(11-2) = 9$.  We can now rearrange the product
$$
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 =\\
(2 \cdot 6) \cdot (3 \cdot 4) \cdot (5 \cdot 9) \cdot (7 \cdot 8) \equiv\\
1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}
$$
That is, by grouping the integers from $2$ to $11 - 2$ into $\frac{11 - 3}{2} = 4$ pairs of multiplicative inverses, we have shown that 
$$
2 \cdot 3 \cdots (11 - 2)  \equiv 1 \pmod{11}
$$
which allows us to proceed with the proof.

Comment: Thnx, this is more clear now! They also use a non-trivial definition of the inverse with mod p, how does this follow from the normal definition of the inverse that's given by if (a,m)=1 and a as integer then ä is inverse of a modulo m if aä=1(mod m)?

Comment: For example: if $a = 2$, then we see that $\bar a = 6$ is the inverse to $a$ because we indeed have $a \bar a \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$